# how to keep uiview in view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

i have a view that is required to be stayed on the view when the user scroll up or down in a scrollview.

i managed to let it stay on top of the view but how can i allow it to stay at the bottom of the view when i scroll down ? EDIT: attached picture to explain better.

the view will alway be visible on the view.

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog (@"Content Offset: %f", self.playlistTableview.contentOffset.y);

    if (self.playlistTableview.contentOffset.y > playerPosition) // will keep the view at the top
    {
        CGRect newFrame = self.playerView.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x = 0;
        newFrame.origin.y = +self.playlistTableview.contentOffset.y;
        [self.playerView  setFrame: newFrame];
    }
}
```

[image]

you can see how the NZD have a top overlay that stops

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add your ScrollView and Always Stay view in a container view. So it will not scroll when you do scroll the scroll view. and anytime you can change your always stay view to different frame to top or bottom as u needed

```
UIView--->
      1st subview--->UIScrollView
      2nd subview--->Don't ScrollMeView/Always Stay view
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @vijay

thanks for the reply, i had attached a pics to explain better. i need the view to scroll up and down but within the visible view

Comment: I have added the screenshot for your review.

Comment: Hi VIjay, thanks for the reply. My overlay move with the scrollview n stop top n bottom of the visible of view

Comment: i referred to this app https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/currency/id284220417?mt=8

effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have added your view in contain of UIScrollView.

I mean, main container for your view is UIScrollview, so it'll work as subview of UIScrollview and will follow scrollview properties.
Can you please try to add your view on main view.

```
[self.view addSubView:yourViewObj];
```

If that comes behind the scrollView, then please try with

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourViewObj];
```